# Missing minimum Android version to target v3.2 (API 13)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Why or how can i set Minimum Android to target in VisualStudio (Framework to target in XamarinStudio) to Android v3.2 (API level 13)? There is no such entry in drop down list. Does MonoAndroid have v3.2 framework at all? Therefore i can't get members what is addeded in API level 13.

For example FragmentTransaction.Atach/Detach(fragment). Of course I could step over level 13 and set min target to API 14 but then i lose support for all tablets with v3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Xamarin staff Jonathan Pryor:

> You don't. We decided to skip supporting API 13 to try to keep our
>   download size smaller (which clearly needs work...) and because hardly
>   anything is running API-13: by Google's metrics, only 0.1% of devices
>   run API-13. At the time, API-11 and API-12 both had higher
>   percentages; things have clearly changed, as now they're no longer
>   present:
>
> http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about VisualStudio or XamarinStudio, but you can use the Fragment Support Library for fragment support back to API level 4, including attach/detach.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html

Comment: Why would i mess up with support library when API 13 already natively supports fragments? I just need to set project to build against minimum SDK level 13. But i can't find  the way!